# MySQL Grouping Twice

Tags: mysql

I have a database structure of:

ip   |  yid   |    date

Where `ip` represents a user's IP and `yid` is a specific page ID. I'm trying to group by the `ip` and `yid` column, which I have done below. But then I need to group those results by the `yid`. So it would be grouping it into:

yid | count

Where count is the number of times that the page was called limiting 1 call per ip address.

Right now I have:

```
SELECT `ip`, `yid`, `time`, MAX(`time`), count(*) 
FROM mp_downloads
GROUP BY CONCAT(`ip`, `yid`), `yid`
ORDER BY count(*)  DESC
```

But it's not grouping the page ids after it groups by the distinct `yid` & `ip` combo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This using nested query:

```
select temp.*, count(*) from 
(SELECT `ip`, `yid`, `time`, MAX(`time`)
FROM mp_downloads
GROUP BY CONCAT(`ip`, `yid`))temp group by temp.yid;
```

Answer (score 0):

The normative pattern for getting a count of ip addresses that have accessed a (`yid`) would be:

```
SELECT d.yid
     , COUNT(DISTINCT d.ip) AS ip_count
     , MAX(d.date)          AS latest_time
 FROM mp_downloads d
GROUP BY d.yid
```

---

For best performance, you'd want a suitable index, e.g.

```
... ON mp_downloads (yid, ip, date)
```

There's no need to group by an expression that concatenates two columns. There's no need for a derived table (inline view) or a subquery. If you don't need the latest_time, you can omit that expression.

Comment: Would there be a way to get an average of the `latest_time` in this query?

Comment: If you mean that you want the "latest" time for each `(yid,ip)`, and then you want to "average" those values, that's going to require a subquery (in the SELECT list, or as an inline view), or some tricks with ordering and user defined variables. And the expression to calculate an average is going to depend on the datatype of the `date` column. (If this requirement is part of the specification, then it should be included with the question, not left as a comment on an answer.)

Comment: Just saying though, the other solutions allows one to simply add AVG(time) into the sub-query. I simply wanted to know if there was a simple way to do it via your answer